# Voice calls over IPv6

Tags: ipv6, voip

I have a computer running Ubuntu 16.04. I would like to make voice calls between this computer and another computer also running Ubuntu 16.04.

Both of the computers have IPv6 (one of them has a static IP address). Both of them have IPv4 access through NAT (NAT64 on one of the computers and NAT444 on the other).

Can I make a voice call directly between the two computers without relying on third party services?

Any software available in the standard Ubuntu 16.04 repositories can be installed on both computers if necessary.

Comment: I have tested Twinkle as [suggested](https://askubuntu.com/a/938771/284919). But it appears the Twinkle version in 16.04 does not have IPv6 support. I have also tested Linphone. For the first test I did a call between 14.04 and 16.04 because I only have one 16.04 machine locally. I was able to initiate calls directly to an IPv6 address in both directions. But as soon as the call is answered Linphone on the 14.04 machine segfaults. Another problem is that I have to change a setting from IPv4 to IPv6. And every time Linphone is restarted it flips back to IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this, but the following SIP software is available and is supposed to be ipv6 compatible.

[Twinkle (click here to see more info)](http://www.twinklephone.com/)

Here is how to install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install twinkle twinkle-common twinkle-console
```

The following command brings up a list of all that are available (Twinkle is the only one that specifically mentions a GUI):

```
apt-cache search voip
```

Comment: Does SIP allow direct client to client communication? Or do I also need a server?

Comment: @kasperd I really don't know because I've never used it but it does mention stuff about an SIP provider and it looks like you may need to run a server if not using one but really that is just a guess. https://mfnboer.home.xs4all.nl/twinkle/manual.html

Comment: SIP allows addressing calls by IP address.  This allows the server to be bypassed.  You may have problems traversing your firewall, but that is an issue for all peer-to-peer connections.

Comment: @BillThor Firewall isn't going to be a problem. One end of the connection only has what firewall I choose there to be. And the other end will have its firewall reconfigured to allow this traffic (if there even is a firewall there).

Comment: @BillThor So once I have started `twinkle` on two machines, how do I tell them to call each other? There is a text field where I can tell it who to call, but it seems just typing an IP address does not work.

Comment: @kasperd  You will likely need to port forward the necessary ports on one end or the other.  You can start from ether end as long as the other end has the necessary ports forwarded.  (You will need to call to the external IP address. This is the address returned when you conntect to a what's my ip site.)

Comment: @BillThor I think you misunderstood the question. Port forwarding is a workaround for shortcomings in IPv4, there is no need for such a thing anymore. My problem right now is that I have no idea what I am supposed to enter into the Call textbox in order to initiate a call. I tried typing the IP address of the machine at the other end of the call, but that did not work.

Comment: @BillThor When I type `sip:kasperd@2001:db8:2ddc:aeac:200:5eff:fe00:5300` and click **Dial**. What I see happening on the network is attempts to lookup SRV records for `_sip._tcp.2001.`, that's not how it is supposed to behave. So is that a bug, or do I have to type the address differently?

Comment: If I type `sip:kasperd@2001:db8:2ddc:aeac:200:5eff:fe00:5300_sip._tcp.` I see SRV lookups for `[2001:db8:2ddc:aeac:200:5eff:fe00:5300].`, which is not right either. If I instead configure a fake IPv4 address on the network interface and type `sip:kasperd@192.0.2.3` I see SIP invite packets being sent. This is starting to sound a lot like direct dialing in twinkle has bugs in its handling of IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Should I edit these observations about twinkle into my question, or should I ask a new question?

Comment: I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_VoIP_software and tried installing `linphone`. When I enable IPv6 support in `linphone` and choose to dial `sip:kasperd@[2001:db8:2ddc:aeac:200:5eff:fe00:5300]` it sends SIP invites to `2001:db8:2ddc:aeac:200:5eff:fe00:5300`. So now it sounds even more like `twinkle` is buggy and does not properly support IPv6.

Comment: @kasperd It looks like the IPv6 support is still an open ticket for Twinkle.  See: https://github.com/LubosD/twinkle/issues/6. As you are on IPv6 you should avoid the port forwarding issues.  IPv6 privacy may cause issues if it is enabled as your IPv6 address won't be static.

Comment: @BillThor Even when privacy addresses are used the network interface usually also has a static address. I just need to look up what the static address is and access that. I need to know the static address anyway whenever I ssh to a machine.

Comment: Eventually I realized that `twinkle` actually binds to `0.0.0.0:5060` and I found no setting which will allow me to change that. So it looks like IPv6 support is completely absent from the version of `twinkle` being used on 16.04.

Comment: @kasperd It looks like someone tried to add IPv6 support a couple of years ago, but found the handling of addresses deeply embedded throughout the code.

Comment: @kasperd Actually, I scanned the page too quickly and I now see that ipv6 support is on the "road map" and not part of the current version.